# How to use Erlang Distribution Function Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, probability

I want to randomly generate numbers that follow a Erlang Distribution for an arrival process. I want to set the number of arrivals k as a parameter of the Erlang Distribution.

```py
scipy.stats.erlang.rvs(a, loc=0, scale=1, size=1, random_state=None)
```

I am not so sure what loc and scale mean, as in the documentation they did not really clarify what they represent.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Erlang distribution is a particular case of the Gamma distribution, by checking the [gamma documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html):

> The probability density above is defined in the “standardized” form. To shift and/or scale the distribution use the loc and scale parameters. Specifically, gamma.pdf(x, a, loc, scale) is identically equivalent to gamma.pdf(y, a) / scale with y = (x - loc) / scale. Note that shifting the location of a distribution does not make it a “noncentral” distribution; noncentral generalizations of some distributions are available in separate classes.

In the case of Erlang distribution, `a` should be an integer and the `scale` should be `1/lambda`.